# how to write correct query in wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

what is wrong in my query?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE '%".$searchKey."%'";
```

In this case, query work fine:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE '%hello%'
```

When i try add variable to query, it doesn't work

```
 public function search_result($searchKey)
  {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE '%".$searchKey."%'";
    return $this->wpdb->get_results($query);
  }
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`prepare`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) method.

```
public function search_result($searchKey)
{
    $searchKey = '%'.$searchKey.'%';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_title LIKE %s";
    return $this->wpdb->get_results($this->wpdb->prepare($query, [$searchKey]));
}
```